# Input.GetKey("f") does not do anything when f i pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Within my, if function, the `Input.GetKey("t")` command does not work.
The `Restart` method is called when I remove the contents from the if function and place them outside.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour 
{
    bool gameHasEnded = false; 

    public float restartDelay = 2f;
    public GameObject LevelFailedUI;
    public GameObject LevelCompleteUI;

    public void CompleteLevel () 
    {
        if (LevelFailedUI == true)
        {
            LevelCompleteUI.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public void EndGame ()
    {
        if (gameHasEnded == false)
        {
            gameHasEnded = true;
            LevelFailedUI.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKey("t"))       //nothing happens when "t" is pressed.
            { 
                Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
            }
        }
    }

    void Restart () 
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        LevelFailedUI.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're using [the wrong overload of `GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html). The `GetKey(String)` overload is for _named keys_ (like `"up"` and `"enter"` - and there's no key _named_ `"t"`). What happens if you use the `Input.GetKey(KeyCode)` overload instead?

Comment: I don't think so. It worked perfectly when I created the player movement.

Comment: Does `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because unity has to be inside the function and also hasn't reached the check before reaching the `if` statement and you press the button during one frame which is basically impossible. You have to check for input constantly that is why it is done inside the `Update` function.

```
void Update() {
  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.T) && gameHasEnded) {
    Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
  }
}
public void EndGame() {
  if (gameHasEnded == false) {
    gameHasEnded = true;
    LevelFailedUI.SetActive(true);
  }
}
```